# Can i use Linq to iterate/filter my web.config AppSettings?

Tags: asp.net, linq, appsettings

i'm trying to figure out how I can use Linq to filter out some of my appsettings from my web.config file.

i'm trying to do something like the following (which has wrong syntax) :-

```
var query = from q in System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys
            where q.StartsWith("Foo")
            select q);
```

what have I done wrong?

edit: added screenie (here's [a link to it](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5516/errorji.png))

[alt text http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5516/errorji.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5516/errorji.png)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? The above looks alright...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this if you want the values:

```
var settings = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

var query = from string q in settings.Keys
            where q.StartsWith("Foo")
            select settings[q];
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be because KeysCollection only implements IEnumerable not IEnumerable`<T`>. Try using the Cast method on the Keys property first, something like:

```
var query = from q in System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.Cast<string>()
        where q.StartsWith("Foo")
        select q;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to think of the following

```
            var appStngVals = from s in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.OfType<string>()
                      where s.StartsWith("Foo")
                      select ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[s];
```

(as applicable to a console app)